# How to use the ISNULL/empty Function (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Trying something like this. My code is find the value of cell B7 of Sheet1 in column A of Sheet15. If it is not found, do nothing. If it is found, write the value in the cell next to the found value to the next available cell in column F of Sheet4.

I have this number in Sheet1

[image]

Code will find that Sheet1 value in Sheet2 Col"A" then copy the Col"B" value that is "156".

[image]

After that code will paste that "156" VALUE IN Sheet3.Range("C2") to till where Col"B" used range end.

[image]

Looking forward to your help.

```
Dim lastR4  As Long

        lastR4 = Sheet4.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheet15.Range("A2:B2") Is Empty Then
        Exit Sub
        Else
       Sheet4.Range("F11:F" & lastR4).Value = Sheet15.Range("A" & _
                             WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value, Sheet15.Range("A:A"), 0)).Offset(0, 1)

   End If
```

Comment: You are trying to write the value from one cell `Sheet15.Range("A" & whatever).Offset(, 1)` to a range (an array) `Sheet4.Range("F11:F" & lastR4).Value`. Think about it for a while and then clarify what you want to write where.

Comment: Hi, Actually i am begginer to VBA and unable to guess the thing what you are saying. @VBasic2008 I just want that if Sheet15 is empty  then code should return empty.

Comment: Try something like this: *The code is trying to find the value in cell `B7` of `Sheet1` in column `A` of `Sheet15`. If it is not found, do nothing (or return a message box). If it is found, write the value of the cell next to the cell of the found value to the next available cell in column `F` of `Sheet4`.* Best do it in [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65868328/edit).

Comment: @ VBasic2008 Thank you i edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next slightly adapted code, please:

```
Sub testFillDat()
    Dim lastR4 As Long
    
    lastR4 = Sheet4.Range("E" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet15.Range("A2:B2")) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If Sheet15.Range("B2") = "" Then
            Sheet4.Range("F11:F" & lastR4).Value = 0
        Else
            Sheet4.Range("F11:F" & lastR4).Value = Sheet15.Range("A" & _
                WorksheetFunction.match(Sheet1.Range("B7").Value, Sheet15.Range("A:A"), 0)).Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    
    End If
End Sub
```

If there is no match of "B7" (Sheet1) in "A:A" (Sheet15) the code will raise an error. It can be adapted to catch it, but I only tried to show you how checking if a range with multiple cells is empty... In rest, your code should work.

Comment: Thank you sooo much @FaneDuru as always. I just need one more thing that is if Sheet15.ColB values is empty then code should paste 0 in the Sheet4 range

Comment: @Learning: Then, try testing the updated code.

Comment: this error is occur, https://pasteboard.co/JL6oK5S.png

Comment: @Learning: This is happening because you did not correctly copy the above code... `""` is not the same with `0` (zero). You should use `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet15.Range("A:A")) = 0`. The same in the above line using `WorksheetFunction.CountA(...)`. It should return a `Long`, not an empty string... You must learn a little more about the variable declarations and their meaning.

Comment: oh yes, i corrected the mistake but it does not paste the 0 if the concern cell has not value in it.
The problem is that sometimes Sheet1.B7 values is not available in sheet15 if such situation is happen then i have to replace the empty cell with zero so code would paste 0 on Sheet4.F11:F

Comment: Sheet15 with id and value https://pasteboard.co/JL6tRpd.png and sometime sheet15 will be without ID and value like this https://pasteboard.co/JL6uf3s.png if it is empty then 0 value will be pasted on Sheet4 range F11:F till the ColE used range

Comment: @Learning: It looks I misunderstood your request and I used coll "A:A" Instad of "B:B". But looking to your pictures, shouldn't it be enough to check if only "B2" is empty? I will adapt the code in this regards.

Comment: @Learning: Please, test the updated code.

Comment: @Learning:  Glad I could help! But, doing what you initially requested, it should not work because of the header in  "B1", which will not let `CountA` returning zero...

Comment: Yes thats why i uploaded the pictures to show you what is actually the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup Using `Application.Match`

- Using `Application.Match` is easier and cleaner then using `WorksheetFunction.Match` because you can test the result with `IsError` or `IsNumeric`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    ' The cell containing the lookup value.
    Dim cel1 As Range
    Set cel1 = Sheet1.Range("B7")
    
    ' First 'available' cell in column `E` column, but in column `F`.
    Dim cel4 As Range
    Set cel4 = Sheet4.Range("E" & Sheet4.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)
    
    ' Range from cell `A1` to the last non-empty cell.
    Dim rng15 As Range
    Set rng15 = Sheet15.Range("A1", Sheet15.Range("A" & Sheet15.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    ' The index of the found value. If not found, returns error value.
    ' Therefore we use 'Variant'.
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    cMatch = Application.Match(cel1.Value, rng15, 0)
    
    ' Test if found with 'IsNumeric()'. You can also use 'Not IsError()'
    ' instead. Or even 'IsError()', but then switch the statements.
    If IsNumeric(cMatch) Then
        cel4.Value = rng15.Cells(cMatch).Offset(, 1).Value
        MsgBox "Value '" & cel1.Value & "' copied.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Value '" & cel1.Value & "' not found.", vbCritical, "Fail"
    End If

End Sub
```

### EDIT

- Adjust the sheets and cells appropriately.

**Fill Range with Found Value**

```
Sub test2()

    ' The cell containing the lookup value.
    Dim cel1 As Range
    Set cel1 = Sheet1.Range("B7")
    
    ' Range from cell 'E2' to the last non-empty cell, but column `F`.
    Dim rng4 As Range
    Set rng4 = Sheet4.Range("E2", Sheet4.Range("E" & Sheet4.Rows.Count) _
        .End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1)
    
    ' Range from cell `A1` to the last non-empty cell.
    Dim rng15 As Range
    Set rng15 = Sheet15.Range("A1", Sheet15.Range("A" & Sheet15.Rows.Count) _
        .End(xlUp))
    
    ' The index of the found value. If not found, returns error value.
    ' Therefore we use 'Variant'.
    Dim cMatch As Variant
    cMatch = Application.Match(cel1.Value, rng15, 0)
    
    ' Test if found with 'IsNumeric()'. You can also use 'Not IsError()'
    ' instead. Or even 'IsError()', but then switch the statements.
    If IsNumeric(cMatch) Then
        rng4.Value = rng15.Cells(cMatch).Offset(, 1).Value
        MsgBox "Value '" & cel1.Value & "' copied.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Value '" & cel1.Value & "' not found.", vbCritical, "Fail"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: But it is not updating the values in Sheet4.Range("E" & Sheet4.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1), Sheet15 value is in % that will be copy and paste

Comment: If the value in `B7` is `15`, then you have to use `15/100` i.e. `cel1.Value  / 100`, to find `15%` in `rng15`. Or format `B7` also as percentage, but make it 100 times smaller.

Comment: Let me update my question once again with pictures.

Comment: @ VBasic2008 updated my question with pictures please have a look

Comment: `Sheet1.Range("B7")` is `Sheet1.Range("B4")` in the image. Have you changed that?

Comment: No i did not changed it if you see my code above it has same cell